# Display all data in dropdown from database

Tags: php, mysql

i am using Php/Mysql , i have the client table and trying to display data in a drop down list. Unfortunately, only one client is displayed in drop down which i have the total of 3 clients. Why only one ? For example : Michael King, Michael Jordan , Michael John when i select all the data from table and make an output to display in dropdown, Michael John is only in the dropdown.

```
Here my Mysql code :

//All data is selected from client_tb
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM client_tb";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

        $id = $row['id'];
        $lname = $row['lname'];
        $fname = $row['fname'];

}

?>

//my dropdown which will show the clients from client_tb but only one will appear.


<option value ="<?=$lname?><?=$fname?>"><?=$lname?> , <?=$fname?> </option> </select><br><br>
```

Comment: You have to put the option inside the loop

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve dropdown outside the while loop. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM client_tb";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$options =array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{    
       $options[] =$row;    
}
```

Your dropdown:

```
<select name="">
  <?php
  foreach($options as $option):
      echo '<option value ="'.$option['lname'].''.$option['fname'].'">'.           
            $option['lname'].','.$option['fname'].'</option>';
  endforeach;
  ?> 
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add your db query into a function , then call it.

```
    function myFunction() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM client_tb";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {    
          $myvalues[] =$row;    
          }
   return $myvalues;

}
```

Now the dropdown, 
Note the options are inside the loop

```
 <select name="">
 <?php foreach($myvalues as $myvalue) {
echo '<option value="'.$myvalue['lname'].''.$myvalue['fname'].'">'.           
       $myvalue['lname'].','.$myvalue['fname'].'</option>';
         }
   ?> 
 </select>
```